# styling and resizing and coloring received notification push in notification bar

Tags: java, android

I use parse and I receive notification push in notification bar with this json code:

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf 
                   sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fsdf sdf sdfs dfs df sdf",
        "title": "my title",
        "url": "http://www.wepars.com/12000"
    }
}
```

is it possible to customized size/color/and number of words in this push notification ?

1- I want show all message text in notification bar
2- change background color
3-style color and size of title also message

here is my code...please guide me to do that

```
 private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

        intent.putExtras(parseIntent.getExtras());

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);


    }
```